# Array as angular field

Tags: angular

I have a response like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "ab",
        "description": "gazeta",
        "published": true,
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "content": null
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "content": null
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "content": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "ba",
        "description": "car",
        "published": false,
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "content": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "ab",
        "description": "gazeta",
        "published": true,
        "comments": []
    }
]
```

I have a service:

```
export interface tuts{
  id: number;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  published: boolean;
  comments: {id: number; content: string;}[]
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TutorialsService {

  private baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/tut/";
  
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  
  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<tuts[]>(`${this.baseUrl}`+'tutorials');
  }
}
```

I tried to divide to two different interfaces, but still got Pic.1.
And the list-component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tutorials',
  templateUrl: './tutorials.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tutorials.component.css']
})
export class TutorialsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private tutorialsService: TutorialsService) { }
  tutorials: Observable<Tutorials[]>;
  tutorial : Tutorials = new Tutorials();
  deleteMessage=false;
  tutoriallist:any;
  isupdated = false;   

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isupdated=false;
    this.tutorialsService.getAll().subscribe(data =>{
      this.tutorials = data;
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <table  class="table table-hover table-sm" >
      <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr>             
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
           <tr *ngFor="let tut of tutorials">
              <td>{{tut.id}}</td>
              <td>{{tut.title}}</td>
              <td>{{tut.description}}</td>
              <td>{{tut.comments}}</td>
            </tr> 
      </tbody><br>
  </table>
</div>
```

And i got this
[image: Pic.1]

insted iteration of nested arrays.

Im using Angular 7.
For endpoint i would like to display my response like Tree.
Should I use something from angular 14?

Comment: in the list-component please console log the data in the subscribe function

Comment: `(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{id: 1, title: 'ab', description: 'gazeta', published: true, comments: Array(3)}
1
: 
{id: 2, title: 'ba', description: 'car', published: false, comments: Array(1)}
2
: 
{id: 3, title: 'ab', description: 'gazeta', published: true, comments: Array(0)}
length
: 
3
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting `[object Object]` is because `comments` is an array. So you have to add another `ngFor` for that and loop through it.

Try this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let tut of tutorials">
    <td>{{tut.id}}</td>
    <td>{{tut.title}}</td>
    <td>{{tut.description}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let comment of tut.comments">
        <span>{{comment.propertyName}}<span>
    </td>
  </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

`tut.comments` is an array, therefore its elements are printed each as `[object Object]`. You need to iterate over the array in order to print each element.

Maybe something like this:

```
<td>
  <ul *ngIf="tut.comments.length">
    <li *ngFor="let comment of tut.comments">{{comment.id}}: {{comment.content}}</li>
  </ul>
</td>
```

(Maybe you could also check `content` of valid values.)